# apt install android-tools-adb is returning 404

Tags: android, ubuntu

After much trying with the android emulator I'm trying to use my device for debugging. I read that I need to `install android-tools-adb`, however, I'm receiving the following `404` error - I'm not sure which repo I should be using (and I have universe activated) :

```
The following NEW packages will be installed:
android-tools-adb
0 to upgrade, 1 to newly install, 0 to remove and 7 not to upgrade.
Need to get 71.7 kB of archives.
After this operation, 204 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty/universe amd64 android-tools-adb amd64 5.1.1r36+git20160322-0ubuntu5
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/a/android-tools/android-tools-adb_5.1.1r36+git20160322-0ubuntu5_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

I have tried the suggestion `--fix-missing` and update, and without success, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try download http://ftp.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/a/android-tools/
and install manually  - `synaptic`, `gdebi` and etc.

Comment: I downloaded the .deb file and tried installing it manually and it hadn't worked.

Comment: I ended up upgrading the distribution